# How do I create an array of unique field values in React with data from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm retrieving the data from Firestore and then displaying it in a list with the following code:

```
{ docs && docs.map(doc => (
     <ul key={doc.id}>               
        <li>
             <button>
                  <Link to={`/tag/${doc.myTag}`}>
                      {doc.myTag}
                  </Link>
             </button>
        </li>
     </ul>
))}
```

This outputs **every** tag. At first I want array of data fetched from Firestore and set into my own new array. After that, I would like to remove duplicates and show just unique tags. What would be the correct way to do this?

I'm thinking to create a new array and then use filter + indexOf, or something similar, but I need to create an array of all the tags first, which is where I'm having the problem.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: tags are in string or in other form?

Comment: The tags are a string, stored in a normal Firestore document, e.g. I need the tag from each document in an array (I think)

createdAt: 26 October 2020 at 18:29:42 UTC+8
myBody "some body terxt"
myTag "a tag in a string"
URL "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/imageURL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly get your question, the following should help:

To get data from Firestore to array. First of all you have to iterate over an object of Firestore and then save them to a new array.

**For Example:**

```
 documentName.firestore().collection("collectionName").doc(yourDoc).get().then(queryResult =>{

      //Here create new array and push your data to array after making it unique 
      //using set or any other function

  });
```

**queryResult** is a **[DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html)**: It "contains data read from a document in your **Firestore** database. The data can be extracted with **.data()** or **.get()** to get a specific field."

Comment: That's the one, thank you Suleman.  You understood my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const docs = [ {tag: 'test'},
              {tag: 'test1'},
              {tag: 'test2'},
              {tag: 'test2'},
              {tag: 'test2'}
             ];

const unique = [...new Set(docs.map(({tag})=> tag))];
console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Cheers @UKS, but it's getting the array in the first place which is the problem. I don't know how to extract the data from Firestore into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solution is is new Set?

```
let clearDocs = [...new Set(docs)];
```

Comment: The 'docs' are already unique, it's the tag field within each doc that I need